# Binary search guessing game server side in java

Tags: java, sockets, search, server, binary-search

I am beyond confused by this program with networking. I am supposed to create a guessing server that creates a socket at 5150 and awaits a client. My server isn't supposed should play the game with any numbers of sequential clients and runs continuously until a client connects and sends "SHUT DOWN" as its initial message. It is supposed to implement the binary search program where a client sends it two numbers indicated the lower and upper boundaries of the list. My server is supposed to reply with a guess and then it receives a message from the client on if the number is high, low, won, or lost the game. And obviously when the game is over the connection between the client and server ends.
This is my code so far I am struggling hard core on what is even going wrong!! Any help what so ever or examples would be much appreciated!

```
public class GuessingServer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String inputLine = "";
        int num1 = 0;
        int num2 = 0;
        int guess = 0;
        String response = "";
        try {
            //set up server
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5150);
            //accept the client (socket)
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            //try to creates scanner and print writer
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter print = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);

            //do game stuff:
            while(scan.nextLine()!= null){
                    if(inputLine.equals("SHUT DOWN")){
                        //shuts down the server
                        serverSocket.close();
                    }   
            //scanner to read the line:
            inputLine = scan.nextLine();
            Scanner line = new Scanner(inputLine);
            if(response != ""){
                while(line.hasNext() == true){ //while the scanner line has something next in it 
                    //get the numbers
                    num1 = line.nextInt();
                    num2 = line.nextInt();
                    //decide and send guess to client:
                    guess = (((num2 - num1)/2)+num1);
                    print.println(guess);
                    System.out.println(guess);
                }
            }else if (response.equals("high") || response.equals("low")){
                while(line.hasNext() == true){ //while the scanner line has something next in it 
                    //get the numbers
                    num1 = line.nextInt();
                    num2 = line.nextInt();
                     //-->decide and send guess to client:
                    guess = (((num2 - num1)/2)+num1);
                    print.println(guess);
                    System.out.println(guess);
                }
            }
            else if(response.equals("won") || response.equals("lost")){
                    //game is over:
                scan.close();
                line.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } 

            scan.close();
            line.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: "sequential clients" what do you mean by this? If multiple users can play at the same time then normally you would need Runnable class, and spawn a Thread for each player

Comment: I honestly don't know exactly what it means, but I don't think we need that we are only coding the server side of this for my lab and using a junit test file for this program

Comment: My answers further down may help you then. We did a similar thing when I did a network programming course

Comment: the part with creating threads I don't think we have learned how to do that, is there another way or does it have to be that way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it.

Have a class for your game server which implements Runnable e.g.

```
class GameThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // Game logic here.
        // Read user input
        // If a user guesses the right number, call shutdown on GuessingGame class
}
```

And your Game server program which creates the Threads e.g.

```
class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while(true) {
            // Accept connections
        }
        // create threads
    }

    void shutDown() {
        // Cleanup
        // Terminate threads
        // Close connections
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

This allows for multiple connections to your Game server